# Identifier too long

Tags: vba, excel

I am faced with this problem: "Identifier too long". What can I do to fix this? I tried using a break "_" . But there will another error: Missing end bracket. Thanks guys.

```
 Sub Netting()

     Dim Found As Range
     Dim LR As Long
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim cell As Range
     Dim a As Variant, v As Variant, num

     Set ws = Sheets("PAYABLES - OUTFLOWS")

     Set Found = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Invoice Amount", _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
     If Found Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

     a = [{"991",1042;"916", 1042;"954",261;"975",3004;"938",726;"901",762;"482",728; _
            "482",728;"934",723;"200",724;"201",724;"952",724;"992",3030;"980",3207;"116",626;"939",722;"390",517;"484",548;"339",59;"141",717;"935",59;"994",3370;"140",8408;"950",775;"370", 734 }] 'create 2-d lookup array

     LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
     Found.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
     ws.Cells(1, Found.Column + 1).Value = "Netting"

     For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Range("C2"), ws.Cells(LR, 3))
        num = CStr(Mid(cell.Value, 3, 3))
        v = Application.VLookup(num, a, 2, False)
        cell.EntireRow.Cells(Found.Column + 1).Value = IIf(IsError(v), "", v)
     Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit on the number of characters per line. You can accomplish this using a much simpler way. Add your data to a spreadsheet ("Sheet1" for example) and in column A and column B.

```
Sub Assign2DVector()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim a As Variant
    a = ws.Range("A1:B20").Value ' set to whatever your actual range is
End Sub
```

Comment: This is part of my current codes only. The project I am working on requires me to create a new column and assign values to it base on another column. I will edit my original post to show my work so far. Thanks

Comment: Hafiz, again the problem in your code is that the assignment statement is too long. So instead of having that data hard coded, add it to separate worksheet (call it SourceData for example), and use the code I have in my answer

Comment: Hi jeanno, really appreaciate you taking your time to assist me. I'm still not quite sure understand. Can you explain it to me? I am still quite new to the VBA environment. Cheers.

Comment: what I am saying this line in your `a = [{"991",1042;"916", 1042;"954",261;"975",3004;"938",726;"901",762;"482",728; _
            "482",728;"934",723;"200",724;"201",724;"952",724;"992",3030;"980",3207;"116",626;"939",722;"390",517;"484",548;"339",59;"141",717;"935",59;"994",3370;"140",8408;"950",775;"370", 734 }] ` code is no good. Create a new worksheet in your workbook called `SourceData`, and the code I have provided to create the 2D vector. Make sure you change `Sheet1` to `SourceData` and set the correct range