# Excel - Hard Coded Array - Identifier too Long

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-2010, udf, vba

I am trying to create a few UDFs to make my vlookups perform a little better.  The problem with the [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312342/identifier-too-long) I have found is they require references to local workbooks, and I will be emailing these workbooks for evaluation to other people (the data can't just have the values pasted either, formulas must be intact).

Is there another work around that allows excel to have the following in a function:

```
    a = [{500,"Baltimore";501,"Chicago";....100 other records...;1000,"Vancouver"}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You can put a hidden sheet that contains the table then it would refer to that instead.

Comment: That will probably be my alternative, I was hoping to take advantage of the speed and security of having all the lists in a macro (several of the lists will  be privileged information), and I have yet to be able to find a way to set a password to prevent someone from unhiding a worksheet, but a module can be password protected so it can't be opened/viewed.